# Ubuntu bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I am using this script to start 2 executables on bootup on my vps :

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/executable1
/path/execytable2
```

However it only starts one of them not both of them.

Comment: The one that isn't starting is failing because of unstated assumption you have made. You need to gather more data to figure out what that assumption is, and how it be corrected ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i start it via terminal it loads normally.

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x scriptname` and see what it's doing (and if you can add some verbosity to your executables so that you're sure how far they exeucte

Comment: Its working fine with bash -x scriptname

Comment: Then your assumption is that the bootup environment is the same as an interactive one. Dump the environment to a file. Dump any error output to a file.

Comment: Does the first command finish?  The second won't be run until it does.

Comment: No. Both commands run executables for servers(so they are running non stop)

Comment: @user3913519 You can add an `&` after the first command, though a service sounds like a better option for this.

Answer (score 1):

Run the commands in the background

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/executable1 &
/path/execytable2 &
```

Comment: Now neither of them loads on bootup.